# Screen Stretching in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

So I am making a Android Application Using LibGDX and Eclipse. I made a Core-/Desktop and Android-Project.

When I run my game in the desktop project, nothing is stretched out to the ground, but when I try to run it on my Galaxy S4, the screen gets all stretched out to the bottom of the screen.

This is the First class of my little App. (in Core)

```
package com.mygdx.ghost;

import states.GSM;
import states.PlayState;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.mygdx.ghost.handler.Content;

public class Ghost extends ApplicationAdapter {

    public static final String TITLE= "Ghost Hunter";
    public static final int WIDTH = 480;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 800;

    public static Content res;

    private SpriteBatch sb;
    private GSM gsm;

    public void create () {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f,0.2f,0.3f,1);

        res = new Content();
        res.loadAtlas("pack.pack", "pack");

        sb = new SpriteBatch();
        gsm = new GSM();
        gsm.push(new PlayState(gsm));
    }

    public void render () {

        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        gsm.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        gsm.render(sb);
    }
}
```

I am using 480x800 because I was promised that would be the game dimensions and not the screen dimensions.

I used the dimensions in the desktop project like this:

```
package com.mygdx.ghost.desktop;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.mygdx.ghost.Ghost;

public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new     LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.width = Ghost.WIDTH;
        config.height = Ghost.HEIGHT;
        config.title = Ghost.TITLE;

        new LwjglApplication(new Ghost(), config);
    }
}
```

Do I use them the same in my andriod project?

Comment: I don't see you actually USING the width or height constants anywhere.

Comment: @noone You opened my eyes, I think I forgot to add the dimensions in the android project... Do I use them the same as in the edit?

Comment: You cannot do that, because Android doesn't have "windows" of arbitrary size like Desktop has. Read [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Projection,-viewport,-&-camera) and [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera) and [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports).

Comment: Okay I read all that, but still I am stuck, but thanks for the help.

Comment: Figured it out, thanks bro